# How to compare the marginal variation of two groups with a big difference frequency between them?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, proportion, logarithm, paired-data, percentage

I have two different groups *(A)* and *(B)* and I would like to compare the marginal variation of the frequency for each time of both groups but, each one of them has a different frequency for a given variable *(x)* and time *(t)* according to Table1:

**Table1**

[image: Table 1]

The problem is: assuming the greater frequency the bigger is variance, so it might not be interesting to compare them in order to do an analysis. It's like that story of two people vying for Heads-or-Tails match, but one of them throws the coin 10 times while the other plays 100 times.

So, how should I do to compare those marginal variation?

I have thought apply natural logarithm over those frequencies in order to antialise the difference between them according to Table2. However, I don't know how to interpretate those marginal variations after that logarithmic antialiasing. What should I say about these news percentages?

**Table2**

[image: Table2]

*Note: decimal places are in the French standard*